# PostgreSQL Time without timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 3k data in my database and i would like to generate a random time for the column of operation_start and operation_end.

the code below is the one I'm using manually update each operation_start and operation_end

```
UPDATE dashboard.inventory
SET operation_start = '1:00:43',
operation_end = '2:00:43',
update_date = NOW()
WHERE terminal_id = '01231238';
```

but updating all 3k data is a pain. I tried googling but there seems to be no answer except for with datestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use time arithmetic.  However, this might be simpler in two steps because you seem to want the end time to be one hour after the start:

```
UPDATE dashboard.inventory
    SET operation_start = '00:00:00' + floor(random() * 23*60*60) * interval '1 second',
        update_date = NOW()
    WHERE terminal_id = '01231238';

UPDATE dashboard.inventory
    SET operation_end = operation_start + interval '1 hour'
    WHERE terminal_id = '01231238';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The remaining problem for me now that the seconds at the end became decimal unit. Like this: "08:17:14.372876"

Comment: @ElijahLeis . . . I think `floor()` takes care of that.